# unable to change the Global Navigation in SharePoint Modern Pages

Tags: office-365, 2016, modern-experience, modern-pages

I wanted to add a link to the Global (Top) navigation in a site collection.

I went to the site settings and added a header with link.

It is appearing in all site pages except the SharePoint modern Pages.

What should I change to add a link in modern pages?

Comment: I tested this and was able to add a links that appeared both on classic and modern pages. I added the links via the Top Link Bar. Can you share a screenshot or something showing where you added the link?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to do it. 
Because you don't have option to add custom JS Or custom CSS towards modern site page.

Comment: thanks, but where is it picking the top navigation from?